# Iterate nested object with for loop

Tags: javascript

how can I get the values of a nested object in a loop? I need to iterate through both levels:

```
for (let unit in ds1.units) {      
    for (let ports in ds1.units[unit].switchPorts) {
        console.log(ports)
    }
}
```

}

Object looks like this:
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdGs3.png)
There is no output. When I access the value with `ds1.units[unit].switchPorts` I get it. Also I get the `unit` after the first for loop.

Comment: Post input object as actual code (a pic is useless) and post what you expect and what you actually get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't iterate Object by default.
Hence, there are multiple ways, but I prefer to convert the key to array.
So the code would be:

```js
for (let unit of Object.keys(ds1.units)) {      
    console.log(ds1.units[unit].switchPorts)
}
```

Also we're going to use `of` instead of `in` because `of` going to retrieve the value instead of index.

For test case:

```js
ds1 = {
   units: {
      1: {
          switchPorts: 5,
        },
      2: {
          switchPorts: 6,
      }
   }
}


for (let unit of Object.keys(ds1.units)) {      
    console.log(ds1.units[unit].switchPorts)
}
```

Comment: This throughs an exception: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'switchPorts').

Comment: Are you sure you pass same object as screenshot? It works in my side. run the test case code I provided

Comment: I suspect you're fetching this from server? and you try to access even before the data received? because no way it's undefined unless the variable is not defined initially

Comment: Sorry I had a typo in the function. Youre code works perfectly fine. Thanks for explanation and code!